# Understanding of linear regression coefficients

Tags: regression

I know that commonly it is said that the regression weights (i.e. the estimated "beta") is the relevance of the associated independent variable when all other variables are held constant. I have two questions with regards to this aspect:

- Why isn't it that the beta weight is the relevant of the associated independent variable when everything else is set to **zero** (instead of held constant)? I am thinking of a line, where we see the slope of the regression weight of interest when we set the other slopes to zero..
- Is this relevant always as compared to the regression "baseline" (i.e. the intercept)?

Thanks

Comment: Well, zero is a constant.

Comment: @jbowman Zero is a constant but it may not have a meaningful interpretation for a predictor variable whose values are much larger than zero, say.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement - Oh, sure, it's just the "instead of held constant" phrase that triggered my response. I also just noticed the OP's apparent confusion between setting a variable to zero and setting the parameter (estimate) to zero in the next sentence.

Comment: I have a difficulty in working out  meaning of regression weights as propagated here. Further, the langusge  of question and its body is incomprehensible from an angle of a statistician. The answer too is self- styled lacking a genesis of  multiple regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other predictor variables in the model have to be set to plausible values.

As an example, let's say you have a model of the form:

```
Cholesterol_Level = beta0 + beta1*Blood_Pressure + beta2*Body_Weight + error (1)
```

If the model concerns adults, it doesn't make sense to set Body Weight to 0 kg and then - after fitting the model to the data - say things like:

```
Among all adults with a Body Weight of 0 kg, we found a significant  
positive linear relationship between Blood Pressure and Cholesterol  
Level.
```

Usually, what we do say is something like this:

```
Among all adults with *the same* Body Weight, we found a significant   
positive linear relationship between Blood Pressure and Cholesterol  
Level.
```

with the tacit understanding that Body Weight is set to a plausible value given the data (e.g., among all adults with a weight of 65kg). It doesn't really matter what that value is (as long as it is plausible given the data) since the relationship between Blood Pressure and Cholesterol Level is the same regardless of the set value for Body Weight.

Comment:

If we want to ignore the effect of Body Weight when estimating the effect of Blood Pressure on Cholesterol Level, all we have to do is fit the following model:

```
 Cholesterol_Level = beta0 + beta1*Blood_Pressure + error (2)
```

This model is obtained by setting beta2 to zero in model (1).  Note that we set the unknown parameter beta2 to zero, NOT the estimated value of this parameter obtained from the data.

Assuming that (i) the estimated value of beta1 is positive after fitting both models to the data and (ii) the test of the hypotheses Ho: beta1 = 0 versus Ha: beta1 != 0 produces a significant p-value, then:

Conclusion for Model 1:

```
We found a significant positive linear relationship between Blood 
Pressure and Cholesterol Level among all adults represented by our 
study *who have the same Body Weight*.
```

Conclusion for Model 2:

```
We found a significant positive linear relationship between Blood 
Pressure and Cholesterol Level among all adults represented by our 
study, *irrespective of their Body Weight*.
```

Comment: In terms of the OP's concern about the "baseline" intercept, he would be correct that the intercept in your model represents the predicted Cholesterol_level at the (biologically impossible) values of 0 Blood_Pressure and 0 Body_Weight. You are completely correct that we must be careful not to apply models to situations for which they are unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks! I think you helped me understand a lot - so setting the other variables to zero would be a possibility too, but might not have an interpretation - hence the point is just to see the "slope" for one independent variable, holding the others variables constant in a "plausible" way - however, I do indeed have another confusion: Could we not set the other *coefficient estimates* to zero, and then the beta estimate of interest describes the relationship between independent variable and response?

Comment: I'm glad this thread helped you - everyone contributed great insights. See my comment added to the original answer.